# pong game in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to move both paddles at the same time:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
            if(event.getY() > screenY/2)
            {
                playerPoint1.set((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
            }

            else if(event.getY() < screenY/2)
            {
                playerPoint2.set((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

but I only can move one paddle at a time, do you have any ideas, how should I modify this method, to make it work properly?

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059127/android-multi-touch

Comment: I got this, thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future programmers having that problem:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    int num = event.getPointerCount();
    for (int a = 0; a < num; a++) {
        int x = (int) event.getX(event.getPointerId(a));
        int y = (int) event.getY(event.getPointerId(a));
        if(y > screenY/2)  playerPoint1.set(x, y);
        if(y < screenY/2)  playerPoint2.set(x, y);
    }
    return true;
}
```